# Sql column name use more than once

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server code, it can works well when I run it, but when I tried to use the it to create view(or create table), it says I used `AccountNo` more than once.

When I change the `AccountNo to`AccountNo1`,`AccountNo2` each..., SQL Server also says I'm wrong...

What's wrong with my query? Who can help me? Thanks very much!

Sql code is:

```
WITH balanceafter (AccountNo,TransactionDateTime)
AS (
    SELECT AccountNo
        ,TransactionDateTime
    FROM account_trans
    WHERE BalanceAfter = 0
        AND BalanceBefore <> 0
        AND TransactionType <> 'Foreign Exchange'
    GROUP BY AccountNo,TransactionDateTime)
    ,balancebefore (AccountNo,TransactionDateTime)
AS (
    SELECT AccountNo
        ,TransactionDateTime
    FROM account_trans trans
    WHERE BalanceBefore = 0
        AND BalanceAfter <> 0
        AND TransactionType <> 'Foreign Exchange'
    GROUP BY AccountNo,TransactionDateTime
    )
SELECT trans.*, new.*
FROM account_trans trans
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT bef.AccountNo
        ,bef.TransactionDateTime
    FROM balancebefore bef
    INNER JOIN balanceafter aft
        ON bef.AccountNo = aft.AccountNo
            AND bef.TransactionDateTime = aft.TransactionDateTime
    ) txn
    ON trans.AccountNo = txn.AccountNo
        AND trans.TransactionDateTime = txn.TransactionDateTime
LEFT JOIN c_info_new new
    ON trans.AccountNo = new.AccountNo
WHERE ParentName <> '******'
    AND AccountType IN ('Customer','Partner')
```

Comment: Use aliasing. You are selecting same column names..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aliasing and change this:

```
select trans.*,new.*
```

to this:

```
select trans.Col1, 
       trans.Col2, 
       trans.AccountNo, 
       new.Col1, 
       new.Col2,
       new.AccountNo as AccountNo2
```

Comment: It's useful,Thank you!